# Make unit tests on xamarin forms project that don't use MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, testing, xamarin.forms

I want to add tests in an mobile app developped with Xamarin Forms but I didn't find any topics about unit testing without MVVM.

I saw : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/unit-testing

but nothing without MVVM pattern

My questions are :

- Is it possible to make unit testing without MVVM pattern ?
- Is it better to implement MVVM pattern before add unit tests ?

Thank's a lot for your replies.

Comment: Unit testing is completely separate from framework & architecture patterns. If you have written code that you want to test, create a unit test project and write tests. If you haven't used a pattern such as MVVM it might be extremely difficult to test because your code is tightly coupled to the platform. You can mock XF in unit tests and run much of your app ([source](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/mocking-xamarin-forms)).

Comment: Thank you @Axemasta, I understand what you mean but I don't have the experience to decide whether to refactor my code to use the MVVM pattern. Can you tell me which parts will be hard to test so I can make a decision.

Comment: When you use MVVM you decouple your app logic from your view. If you want to test the behaviour of a page that doesnt use a viewmodel, you will have to mock UI aswell as test for behaviour in your system. Hard to test basically just means you can't mock / ignore behaviour as part of the test. This is why decouple MVVM with a framework like Prism is really easy to test because the framework encourages you to use interfaces and not have hard coupled behaviour